# How to reopen JPA EntityManager after it gets invalidated with an exception

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a simple spring/hibernate/jpa based application. I am trying to iteration through a list of records from an xml file and persist it into a DB table.

I have 35 records and 3 of them has null values for certain fields which are mandatory in the table.

I get this error: 
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.pilogics.gogabbar.domain.model.entity.UserActivity entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)..

As I don't have control of the data coming through a file, I want to simply skip those 3 records and carry on. But since the entityManager object is invalidated, do have to reinitialize it?

Also, I have this config in spring fopr entity manager factory:

```
  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:jpa/persistence.xml" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="gg-rw" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.pilogics.gogabbar.infra.persistence.hibernate.pojo.*" />
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="false" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" /> 
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And spring injects the entity manager to a dao class:

```
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="gg-rw")
protected EntityManager entityManagerRw;
```

How can I reinitialize entityManager object in my catch block to carry on with the remaining records?

Comment: Reopening an entity manager is not what you must do. Validating and filtering out the invalid entries before getting the exception is what you should do

Comment: Hi JB, thanks for your comments. It seems to be a good idea. I will introduce hibernate bean validation and hopefully that should throw a ConstraintVoilationException and leave the session (entity manager) clean to be used for remaining records. I will let you know if this worked!

Comment: If you plan on relying on Hibernate to do the validation for you based on bean validation, you will have exactly the same problem. Validate the xml records you get (using whatever you like), and then use hibernate to insert the valid records into the database.

Comment: that's very timely answer. thanks again! I did try hibernate validation and was getting the ConstraintVoilationException on the first failing record, but as you said, for the remaining records, I was still getting the same _don't flush the Session after an exception occurs_. I will validate the input beforehand. Although I must admit, this is something so basic that hibernate should have provided an easy way!

Comment: https://antoniogoncalves.org/2010/03/03/bean-validation-with-jpa-1-0/ looks promising! Which allows hibernate validation during '@PrePersist' / '@PreUpdate' and my domain logic on validation still stays within the model (entity itself). Will try in the evening.